# Python http server works locally but connection is refused from another machine

Tags: http, networking, raspberry-pi

I'm running this simple demo Python http server on a Raspberry pi

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import sys
import time

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 80

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Request: %s</p>" % self.path, "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>This is an example web server.</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.argv.pop(0)

    if len (sys.argv):
        serverPort=int(sys.argv.pop(0))

    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

I can `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` and from there `curl localhost` and get the expected output.

However if I `curl raspberrypi.local` (on the machine from which I can ssh) then the connection is refused.

Why does curl work locally but not remotely?

Comment: Localhost is a name for `127.0.0.1`, and addresses in the `127.0.0.0/8` range must immediately loop back inside the host, and can never appear on any network, anywhere. You need to use an external address.

Comment: Or better still 0.0.0.0 in the server.

Answer (score 2):

As @RonMaupin points out you are using the localhost address which is not available outside of the local machine.

Try this change this line

```
hostName = "localhost"
```

to

```
hostName = "your Pi's IP address"
```

You can find the IP address with the following command:

> ifconfig -a

For example, in my case, the above command shows the **Ipv4** address for **eth0** is **10.0.0.162**.

So I would change the code to:

```
hostName = "10.0.0.162"
```

If your Pi has multiple network interfaces (i.e., WiFi and Ethernet) you could also use this:

```
hostName = "0.0.0.0"
```

This will configure the server to listen on all network interfaces. While quick and easy this does have some security implications and should probably not be done on an internet-facing system.